# Search for a particular kind of warning in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Is it possible to search for a particular type of warning in Android Studio? For example, let's say the warning

> Empty method

I know that I can use the inspection tool to get all the results, but if you work in a huge project, it can be very tedious to do that search...

Comment: What do you mean by inspection tool? Is it CTRL+SHIFT+A (Command+Shift+A on OS X)/Run inspection by name? Because if it is I'm not sure what is tedious about that :)

Comment: Yes. In the top menu `Analyse > Inspect code` What is difficult is to find for a particular type of warning once you have the results and there over 7000 warnings :P

Comment: Then use the run inspection by name as I suggested (different from Analyze/Inspect Code). It allows you to select single type of warning to scan for. Let me know if it works and I will post it as an aswer).

Comment: Oh, yes, it was that. I tried it but nothing worked. Seems like in my Mac the combination is `CMD + Alt + SHIFT + I ` Thanks! Post it as a response and I will approve it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [*Run inspection by name*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspection-by-name.html) functionality.

To invoke it you have two options:

- Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows/Linux) and search for *Run inspection by name*
- Use the shortcut for *Run inspection by name*:  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Windows/Linux),

Then search for the inspection name you want to run and hit Enter to run it.